# sqlalchemy orm join error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

ii have this query in sql:

```
select field.field_name FROM 
form 
INNER JOIN 
formField ON form.form_id=formField.form_id 
INNER JOIN field ON formField.field_id = field.field_id 
WHERE form.risk_id = 1;
```

now i am tryin to map it to sqlalchemy ORM like this:

```
session.query(Field.field_name).join(
            FormFieldMap,
            Form.form_id == FormFieldMap.form_id
            ).join(
                Field, 
                FormFieldMap.field_id == Field.field_id
            ).filter(
                Form.risk_id == 1
            ).all()
```

but i am getting this rror why?:

O

```
perationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1066, "Not unique table/alias: 'field'") [SQL: u'SELECT field.field_name AS field_field_name \nFROM field INNER JOIN `formField` ON form.form_id = `formField`.form_id INNER JOIN field ON `formField`.field_id = field.field_id \nWHERE form.risk_id = %s'] [parameters: (1,)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: you may need [table alias](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#using-aliases)

Comment: You've both implicitly referenced `Field` in the query, generating the FROM item, and explicitly joined it, so you get the error about non unique table. Simply put, add `.select_from(Form)` before the 1st join in order to control the left side of it.